# AllowOverride Options Nonfatal=All But .htaccess "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I configured Apache. I use it as follows.
These codes, obstructions are working. No problem.
However, when you type "Options +ExecCGI" in .htaccess, you get 500 errors.
My wish; I would like 500 errors to be ignored even if there is an invalid "Options +ExecCGI" in .htaccess.

```
<Directory "/">
        Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes -MultiViews +IncludesNOEXEC +Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes Limit FileInfo Options=IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

"Nonfatal=All" Could it be a solution? How to use. I try, it does not work.

Comment: Please don't change your question completely. You need to post a new question if you want to ask one.

Comment: error: Your question couldn’t be submitted "Resolve 1 issues before posting" help please.